# The member "methodhiding.parttimeemployee.printfullname()" does not hide an inherited member

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2012, monodevelop

I can't figure out the problem. The program should hide the 'Printfullname()' from the employee class.

```
using System;

namespace MethodHiding
{
     public class Employee
    {
        public string first;
        public string last;

        public void PrintFullName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last);
        }

    }
    public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
        public new void PrintFullname()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last + "- Contractor ");
        }
    }
    public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
    {

    }
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            PartTimeEmployee PTE = new PartTimeEmployee();
            PTE.first = "abc";
            PTE.last = "Sarfraz";
            PTE.PrintFullName();
        FullTimeEmployee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
        FTE.first= "hjk";
            FTE.last = "poi";
                FTE.PrintFullName();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PrintFull**n**ame != PrintFull**N**ame

Answer (score 2):

```
 public virtual void PrintFullName()
 {
        Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last);
 }

 public override void PrintFullName()
 {
        Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last + "- Contractor ");
 }
```

Don't use new unless you have to. Also as Eugene Podskal pointed out c# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

**PrintFullname** doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant **PrintFullName**?

```
public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public new void PrintFullname() < this should be PrintFullName
    {
        Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last + "- Contractor ");
    }
}
```